# Sorry, something went wrong, when clicking on Content and Structure

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, content-and-structure

We have SharePoint 2013 and when users click on content and structure under `Site Settings` > `Site Administration`. They receive an error with Correlation ID. I thought it was the publishing feature, but I did deactivate and then reactive the publishing feature (to be precise: **SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure**) but that did not work.

Here is a dump of the correlation id:

> Size=100;Asynchronous Processing=True;Connect Timeout=15   c4526d9d-1016-4020-bf9e-51f249dd5612
>   03/29/2016 10:30:32.29  w3wp.exe (MKKG1947:0x8318)              0x0988  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8nca    Medium  Application error when access /_layouts/15/sitemanager.aspx, Error=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.ObjectSerializer.DeleteAllowed(Boolean checkPermissions)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.SmtButtonField.FormatDataValue(Object dataTextValue, Boolean encode)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField.OnDataBindField(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)     at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()     at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateRow(Int32 rowIndex, Int32 dataSourceIndex, DataControlRowType rowType, DataControlRowState rowState, Boolean dataBind, ... c4526d9d-1016-4020-bf9e-51f249dd5612
>   03/29/2016 10:30:32.29* w3wp.exe (MKKG1947:0x8318)              0x0988  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8nca    Medium  ...Object dataItem, DataControlField[] fields, TableRowCollection rows, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPGridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect()     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound()     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnPreRender(EventArgs...  c4526d9d-1016-4020-bf9e-51f249dd5612
>   03/29/2016 10:30:32.29* w3wp.exe (MKKG1947:0x8318)              0x0988  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8nca    Medium  ... e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)  c4526d9d-1016-4020-bf9e-51f249dd5612
>   03/29/2016 10:30:32.29  w3wp.exe (MKKG1947:0x8318)              0x0988  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.ObjectSerializer.DeleteAllowed(Boolean checkPermissions)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.SmtButtonField.FormatDataValue(Object dataTextValue, Boolean encode)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField.OnDataBindField(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)     at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()     at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateRow(Int32 rowIndex, Int32 dataSourceIndex, DataControlRowType rowType, DataControlRowState rowState, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem, DataControlField[]... c4526d9d-1016-4020-bf9e-51f249dd5612
>   03/29/2016 10:30:32.29* w3wp.exe (MKKG1947:0x8318)              0x0988  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ... fields, TableRowCollection rows, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPGridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect()     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound()     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.Pr...  c4526d9d-1016-4020-bf9e-51f249dd5612
>   03/29/2016 10:30:32.29* w3wp.exe (MKKG1947:0x8318)              0x0988  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ...eRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) c4526d9d-1016-4020-bf9e-51f249dd5612
>   03/29/2016 10:30:32.29  w3wp.exe (MKKG1947:0x8318)              0x0988  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ajlz0   High    Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.ObjectSerializer.DeleteAllowed(Boolean checkPermissions)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.SmtButtonField.FormatDataValue(Object dataTextValue, Boolean encode)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField.OnDataBindField(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)     at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()     at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.Crea... c4526d9d-1016-4020-bf9e-51f249dd5612
>   03/29/2016 10:30:32.29* w3wp.exe (MKKG1947:0x8318)              0x0988  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ajlz0   High    ...teRow(Int32 rowIndex, Int32 dataSourceIndex, DataControlRowType rowType, DataControlRowState rowState, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem, DataControlField[] fields, TableRowCollection rows, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPGridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect()     at System....  c4526d9d-1016-4020-bf9e-51f249dd5612
>   03/29/2016 10:30:32.29* w3wp.exe (MKKG1947:0x8318)              0x0988  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ajlz0   High    ...Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound()     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean in...  c4526d9d-1016-4020-bf9e-51f249dd5612
>   03/29/2016 10:30:32.29* w3wp.exe (MKKG1947:0x8318)              0x0988  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ajlz0   High    ...cludeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)  c4526d9d-1016-4020-bf9e-51f249dd5612
>   03/29/2016 10:30:32.31  w3wp.exe (MKKG1947:0x8318)              0x0988  SharePoint Foundation           General                         90hv    Unexpected  47af8de9-e8b2-4aad-994a-059f8374575b Stack trace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.CustomizedCss(String cssFile)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.CssLink.MakeCssUrl(SPWeb web, Int32 uiVersion, String cssFile, Boolean bInDesign)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.CssRegistrationRecord.get_CanonicalCssReference()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.CssRegistrationRecord.Equals(CssRegistrationRecord other)     at System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer`1.Equals(T x, T y)     at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Contains(T item)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.RegisterCssReference(Control ctrl, CssRegistrationRecord cssRef)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.CssRegistration.OnInit(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContai...   c4526d9d-1016-4020-bf9e-51f249dd5612
>   03/29/2016 10:30:32.31* w3wp.exe (MKKG1947:0x8318)              0x0988  SharePoint Foundation           General                         90hv    Unexpected  ...ner)     at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath...  c4526d9d-1016-4020-bf9e-51f249dd5612
>   03/29/2016 10:30:32.31* w3wp.exe (MKKG1947:0x8318)              0x0988  SharePoint Foundation           General                         90hv    Unexpected  ..., String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)     at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(String path, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)     at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String path)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.TransferToErrorPage(String message, String linkText, String linkUrl)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.ErrorHandler(HttpApplication app, Boolean errorIsOnErrorPage)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.ErrorAppHandler(Object oSender, EventArgs ea)     at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.RaiseOnError()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.B...  c4526d9d-1016-4020-bf9e-51f249dd5612
>   03/29/2016 10:30:32.31* w3wp.exe (MKKG1947:0x8318)              0x0988  SharePoint Foundation           General                         90hv    Unexpected  ...eginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)     at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime...  c4526d9d-1016-4020-bf9e-51f249dd5612
>   03/29/2016 10:30:32.31* w3wp.exe (MKKG1947:0x8318)              0x0988  SharePoint Foundation           General                         90hv    Unexpected  ....ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)   c4526d9d-1016-4020-bf9e-51f249dd5612
>   03/29/2016 10:30:32.31  w3wp.exe (MKKG1947:0x8318)              0x0988  SharePoint Foundation           General                         aat87   Monitorable     c4526d9d-1016-4020-bf9e-51f249dd5612
>   03/29/2016 10:30:32.32  w3wp.exe (MKKG1947:0x8318)              0x0988  SharePoint Foundation           Micro Trace                     uls4    Medium  Micro Trace Tags: 0 nasq,12 agb9s,388 8nca,0 tkau,0 ajlz0,2 90hv,13 aat87   c4526d9d-1016-4020-bf9e-51f249dd5612
>   03/29/2016 10:30:32.32  w3wp.exe (MKKG1947:0x8318)              0x0988  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://it.cargo.com:80/serviceops/release/_layouts/15/sitemanager.aspx?Source=%7BWebUrl%7D_layouts/15/settings.aspx)). Execution Time=423.895704621677    c4526d9d-1016-4020-bf9e-51f249dd5612

Answer (score -2):

Found the answer using the following link:

http://www.resolvinghere.com/sm/object-reference-not-set-to-an-object-site-content-amp-structure.shtml

Comment: The link no longer exists. Can you give an explanation?